# Extraer posiciones especificas de un array en php

Tags: php, array, arraylist

Del siguiente codigo

```
<?php
$file="datos/datos.txt";
$fopen = fopen($file, "r");
$fread = fread($fopen,filesize($file));
fclose($fopen);
$remove = "\n";
$split = explode($remove, $fread);
$array[] = NULL;
$tab = "\t";
    foreach ($split as $string)
        {
            $row = explode($tab, $string);
            array_push($array,$row);

        }

        
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_slice($array, 2));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Me da este resultado

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 09419075
            [2] => OPERACIONES
            [3] =>  2020-08-20     01:52:41
            [4] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 23638570
            [2] => OPERACIONES
            [3] =>  2020-08-20     02:29:54
            [4] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 10377966
            [2] => OPERACIONES
            [3] =>  2020-08-20     09:03:57
            [4] => 1
        )
```

Lo que quiero hacer es algo que solo me imprima [1] y el [3] de cada arreglo Ejm:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 09419075
            [3] =>  2020-08-20     01:52:41
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 23638570
            [3] =>  2020-08-20     02:29:54
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 10377966
            [3] =>  2020-08-20     09:03:57
        )
```

que me pueden recomendar para solventar esto puede ser php con javascript como quieran porque no tengo idea de hacerlo

Comment: Es algo básico de cualquier lenguaje. ¿Qué has investigado? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Tengo esto pero solo extrae uno necesito que saque los de las posiciones 

$file="datos/datos.txt";
$fopen = fopen($file, "r");
$fread = fread($fopen,filesize($file));
fclose($fopen);
$remove = "\n";
$split = explode($remove, $fread);
$array[] = NULL;
$tab = "\t";

    foreach ($split as $string)
        {
            $row = explode($tab, $string);
            
            array_push($array,$row);
        }
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array[2][1]);
print_r($array[2][3]);
echo "</pre>";

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega a la pregunta lo que tienes hecho, explicando el problema que tienes con ese código. Ya ahí se ve que los datos vienen de un archivo por ejemplo, son detalles que hay que conocer para poder ayudarte partiendo de lo concreto.

Comment: Si, tienes razón ya edite mejor la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, quieres un nuevo array que guarde la misma estructura del array original, pero únicamente con los índices `1` y `3` del sub-array, respetando además dichos índices.

Lo puedes lograr simplemente creando un nuevo array (que llamaremos `$mData` en la respuesta). Y llenaremos ese nuevo array especificando los índices que queremos al recorrer el array original.

El código quedaría así:

```
#Tu array original (aumenté un minuto a la hora por brevedad)
$array=array(
                array(1,"09419075","OPERACIONES","2020-08-20     01:52:41",1),
                array(2,"23638570","OPERACIONES","2020-08-20     01:53:41",1),    
                array(3,"10377966","OPERACIONES","2020-08-20     01:54:41",1),          
    );

#El array con datos extraídos
$mData=array();

foreach ($array as $index=>$row){
    #Por cada $index actual, $mData llenará un sub-array 
    #con los valores en los índices 1 y 3 que encuentre en $row
    $mData[$index][1]=$row[1];
    $mData[$index][3]=$row[3];
}

#Prueba
print_r($mData);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 09419075
            [3] => 2020-08-20     01:52:41
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 23638570
            [3] => 2020-08-20     01:53:41
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 10377966
            [3] => 2020-08-20     01:54:41
        )

)
```

Comment: Es super pero como integro foreach que pusiste con el que tengo en el codigo, ya por lo menos contigo tengo una base para saber buscar la posicion que quiero y eso me ayudo mucho.

Comment: @Jeancito imagino que el array que muestras en la pregunta se produce aquí: `print_r(array_slice($array, 2));` ... entonces lo puedes integrar simplemente haciendo esto: **`$mArray=array_slice($array, 2);`** Y luego **`foreach ($mArray as $index=>$row){`**  ... y todo lo demás igual. Dado que usas `array_slice` sobre un elemento que no conocemos, puede que el código pueda simplificarse aún más. Por eso siempre es bueno poner las cosas en contexto total, no de forma parcial.

Comment: Uso el array_slide porque es un txt que tiene la primera fila como identificador y eso sí no me hace falta por eso lo quito para empezar a mostrar solo la data.. voy a probar el método que me diste gracias de verdad amigo

Comment: @Jeancito revisa que el array que se produce al aplicar slice se llamaría `$mArray` y por tanto el primer `foreach` debe aplicarse a `$mArray`

Answer (score 0):

no estoy seguro si es lo que buscas , pero yo quizás esto te sirva

```
<?php
// Your code here!

$numeros=array(
    array(
        "primero" => 1,
        "segundo" => "09419075",
        "tercero" => "OPERACIONES",
        "cuarto" => "2020-08-20",
        "quinto" => "1"        
        ),
    array(
    
    "primero" => 2,
    "segundo" => "23638570",
    "tercero" => "OPERACIONES",
    "cuarto" => "2020-08-20",
    "quinto" => "1"
    
    ),    
    array(
    
    "primero" => 3,
    "segundo" => "10377966",
    "tercero" => "OPERACIONES",
    "cuarto" => "2020-08-20",
    "quinto" => 1
    
    ),    
        
    );
    

        foreach ($numeros as $key => $numeriten){
        echo $numeriten["segundo"]."    ";
        echo $numeriten["cuarto"]."      ";
    }
```

Comment: Una explicación siempre se agradece

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo podes lograr con la función helper array_filter de php.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php

```
array_filter ( array $array [, callable $callback [, int $flag = 0 ]] ) : array
```

Comment: Un ejemplo de implementación o como implementarlo ayudaría